# Self-referencing many-to-many relationship EF code first

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, breeze, durandal

I work with ASP.NET MVC With Durandal/Breeze templates.

Let's say I have the following class:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }    
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual List<Person> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

With the following EF Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(m => m.Friends)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("Friends"));
```

The database is generated successfully.

**The problem** is when I perform a que

---

ry with Breeze (client side) I have no data for the `Friends` property.

```
    var query = entityQuery.from('Person')
        .where('id', '==', 123)
        .expand("Friends");
```

When the query is executed I get as result the requested People entity with all the data except the Friends property is always an empty array. When I check the Json answer I see that also the data are transmitted. Even data for the Friends property. However they are not linked to the Friends property itself.

**My question:** what do I have to do to have my Friends property filled with values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare a foreign key in Person. Breeze requires the FK to correctly resolve associations.

**Edit:**

I just realized you are asking about a many-to-many relationship. (yeah, I should have read the post title...)
Breeze does not support many-to-many associations. 
However, you could have two one-to-many relationships to work as a many-to-many. (i.e. many-to-one-to-many) In this case, you will need to define the linking table/entity and the foreign key as mentioned earlier. (see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/navigation-properties)

Answer (score 1):

Try this answer:   *Note that this is incomplete because i do not see the other table that you are trying to m-2-m with Persons. ( You will only want to use Persons Table and the 2nd Table , NOT table=Friends.

```
 db.Person
          .Include(c => c.Friends)
          .Where(c => c.Friends.Any(up => up.FriendVlaue == c.FirstName)) //c.from Persons
          .Select(c => new
          {
              PersonID = c.ID,
              PersonName = c.FirstName,
              PersonCount = c.Person.Count()
          })

         {
```

[From This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18281808/how-to-access-related-data-built-by-the-ef+)

Comment: My apologies, this is how to retrieve related data not how to insert.

Answer (score 0):

You should include Friends in the results. You can do this by adding `Include("Friends")`at Server Side API.

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<Person> Persons()
{
   return _contextProvider.Persons.Include("Friends");
}
```

If you don't want to return always the `Friends`reference, you can create another method in the API such as `PersonsWithFriends` as suggested in [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/web-api-controller) (Specialized query actions).

Comment: I tried as you suggested but I still cannot find any data in my Friends property. When I place a breakpoint in my returned statement in my Controller `return _contextProvider.Persons.Include("Friends");` I see my Friends property populated but in my breeze querry I don't see any data for this Friends property. There must be something special to do related to breeze... Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you include your breeze query in JS? I have impemented this before with the same scenario as yours and it works fine.

Comment: My breeze querry (in JS) is already showed in my question, thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you try to remove the expand("Friends"); ??

Comment: :( http://durandalspa.codeplex.com/ in this project I used Durandal and Breeze and there's the same scenario with Order and OrderLines. Take a look, maybe it helps.. Good luck!