# Breeze does not expand my navigation property on a "Many-to-one-to-many" referencing

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, breeze, durandal

At first, I needed to define a "many-to-many" self referencing in EF Code First. Unfortunately this is not supported by Breeze. I mean whenever I query breeze, I don't get no data for my expand on `Friends`. See here: [Self-referencing many-to-many relationship EF code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336511/self-referencing-many-to-many-relationship-ef-code-first/18339969?noredirect=1#18339969)

So the solution seems to be a "many-to-one-to-many".

So here is my classes:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }    
    public string Lastname { get; set; }
    public virtual List<LinkedPerson> Friends { get; set; }
}

public class LinkedPerson
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PersonRelatedId { get; set; }

    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
    public virtual Person PersonRelated { get; set; }
}
```

With the following EF Fluent API:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<LinkedPerson>()
                .HasRequired(p => p.Person)
                .WithMany()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

At runtime, the database is generated successfully but I am still unable to query breeze to retrieve the Friends property. As a result, I get all data in my query except the Friends property.

Does someone have an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified the collection property of the relationship. Use the following fluent mapping.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<LinkedPerson>()
            .HasRequired(p => p.Person)
            .WithMany(p => p.Friends)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```